# Multiple Email Recipients in To, CC, BCC of - AWS Lambda Function with S3 Attachments - Python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-ses

I am trying to send emails notifications on a File creation event in the AWS S3 bucket via the Lambda function (Python code). The below code perfectly works fine but I can include only one email address at a time for To, CC, or BCC list. How to include multiple email recipients in To, CC, and BCC? Appreciate your help in advance (I am new to Python and AWS)
Below is my code that is working perfectly.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/4800344). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or press Ctrl+K, the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Comment: Use a comma delimited list, as a string, of the email addresses you want to send to.

Comment: When I use comma-separated email addresses, the event triggers but does not send emails to the SES verified multiple comma-separated email addresses. Instead, it gives an error telling "Illegal Address" in Cloudwatch logs!

Comment: Sorry for the late responses to your answers. Please help as comma-separated-values are not working